# Bootstrap is not working with build as it does with React.js (springboot API)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I have completed my api which as good developer works perfectly in local, after struggling it is working on server and Heroku also, but bootstrap just works fine using "npm start" in VSC, after run "npm run build", is not working well neither Heroku, LocalHost nor Server, here are screenshots

npm start:
[image: as I am excpeting]

with build in static:
[image: The headache]

I have tried many things but none working, is it realtet to index.html?
All adjust in classes are not working neither, I am using:

"div className="card card-body bg-light" from bootstrap, any advice suggestion I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, Issue is in "index.html" since it will work as statics files while bulding by React, we must add bootstrap, proper and Jquery links , not in "App.js" nor "index.js", and for sure dependencies already isntalled.